# Remove class from multiple elements without Jquery

Tags: javascript

Looking for a **javascript** solution to removing a class from multiple buttons.

I'm trying to manage button state, so that when a button is clicked, the clicked buttons state is set to `active`, and the other buttons reset state.

Thus far I've got the follow, which adds the `active` state to the clicked button, but does not reset state (remove the `active` class) of the other buttons.

**main.js**

```
function handleButtonState(context) {
    // Remove "active" class from all buttons

    // Add "active" class to clicked button
    context.classList.add("active");
}
```

**index.html**

```
<div id="filter_list" class="btn-group btn-group-lg btn-block" role="group">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-success btn-block filter_list_button" onclick="handleButtonState(this)">Rock</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-success btn-block filter_list_button" onclick="handleButtonState(this)">Folk</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-success btn-block filter_list_button" onclick="handleButtonState(this)">Jazz</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What have you tried? [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: There is no `classList.remove('active')` in your code so it won't work.

Comment: classList.remove('active') wouldn't work